# Android, avoid duplicate classes error by modifying dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

In short, Dependency graph looks like this, and there's a duplicate class error because `Libary1_modified` and `Library1` have the same classes..

```
App => Library1_modified
App => Library2 => Library1
```

---

In detail....

I modified a android library and built a jar file (https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-android)
I'm using the built jar using

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
```

Then I wanted to use another library which depends on the above library (the unmodified version)
(https://github.com/segmentio/analytics-react-native)

The dependency from the second library to the first library is stated as

```
 dependencies {
     api 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
}
```

When I build it complains there are `duplicate classes` . 
And yes because `my.jar` is the modified version of `com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+` there are indeed duplicate definitions.

How to use `my.jar` or my version of the library

Comment: Why don't you just create one library? Add everything into `my.jar` and remove the duplicate classes.

Comment: I would if I could, but as I detailed in the OP. the second library is react-native lib and not sure how to merge them with the first library..

Answer (score 0):

I found two workaround

**First solution**

let Library2 depend on modified Library1 and share it with App via `api`

Concretely, I moved  `api fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])` and the jar file to Library2 and removed the dependency from App.

**Second solution**

let App depend on Library1, and exclude library1 when depending on Library2 via `exclude`

```
implementation (project(':@segment_analytics-react-native')) {
    exclude group: 'com.segment.analytics.android', module: 'analytics'
}
```